# Multiple Realsense Cameras in URDF File

Tags: ros, realsense

I have been working with ROS for only a couple weeks, sorry if i misunderstand things. I have made a URDF file with a robot in it. Now I wanted to add two Real-sense D435 cameras onto it so I can see it in Rviz. Following the test file given by Intel I got one camera to show up in the model however, when I try to create a second camera it just doesn't show up.

**Question:** How can I get two Real-sense cameras on my robot?

This is my URDF file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<robot name="mrm" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">
  
  <!-- BGN - Include -->
  <xacro:include filename="$(find mrm_description)/urdf/robot_parameters.xacro" />
  <xacro:include filename="$(find mrm_description)/urdf/links_joints.xacro" />
  <xacro:include filename="$(find realsense2_camera)/urdf/_r435.urdf.xacro"/>
<xacro:include filename="$(find realsense2_camera)/urdf/_r430.urdf.xacro"/>


<m_link_box name="${link_00_name}"
              origin_rpy="0 0 0" origin_xyz="0 0 0"
              mass="1024"
              ixx="170.667" ixy="0" ixz="0"
              iyy="170.667" iyz="0"
              izz="170.667"
              size="1 1 1" />
              
  <m_joint name="${link_00_name}__${link_01_name}" type="revolute"
           axis_xyz="0 0 1"
           origin_rpy="0 0 0" origin_xyz="0 0 0.5"
           parent="base_link" child="link_01"
           limit_e="1000" limit_l="-3.14" limit_u="3.14" limit_v="0.5" />
           
  <m_link_mesh name="${link_01_name}"
              origin_rpy="0 0 0" origin_xyz="0 0 -0.1"
              mass="157.633"
              ixx="13.235" ixy="0" ixz="0"
              iyy="13.235" iyz="0"
              izz="9.655"
              meshfile="package://mrm_description/meshes/Link1-v2.stl"
              meshscale="0.001 0.001 0.001" />
  
  
              
  <m_joint name="${link_01_name}__${link_02_name}" type="revolute"
           axis_xyz="0 1 0"
           origin_rpy="0 0 0" origin_xyz="0 0 0.4"
           parent="link_01" child="link_02"
           limit_e="1000" limit_l="0" limit_u="0.5" limit_v="0.5" />
           
  <m_link_cylinder name="${link_02_name}"
              origin_rpy="0 0 0" origin_xyz="0 0 0.4"
              mass="57.906"
              ixx="12.679" ixy="0" ixz="0"
              iyy="12.679" iyz="0"
              izz="0.651"
              radius="0.15" length="0.8" />
              
  <m_joint name="${link_02_name}__${link_03_name}" type="revolute"
           axis_xyz="0 1 0"
           origin_rpy="0 0 0" origin_xyz="0 0 0.8"
           parent="link_02" child="link_03"
           limit_e="1000" limit_l="0" limit_u="0.75" limit_v="0.5" />
           
  <m_link_cylinder name="${link_03_name}"
              origin_rpy="0 0 0" origin_xyz="0 0 0.4"
              mass="57.906"
              ixx="12.679" ixy="0" ixz="0"
              iyy="12.679" iyz="0"
              izz="0.651"
              radius="0.15" length="0.8" />
              
  <m_joint name="${link_03_name}__${link_04_name}" type="revolute"
           axis_xyz="0 1 0"
           origin_rpy="0 0 0" origin_xyz="0 0 0.8"
           parent="link_03" child="link_04"
           limit_e="1000" limit_l="0" limit_u="0.75" limit_v="0.5" />
           
  <m_link_cylinder name="${link_04_name}"
              origin_rpy="0 0 0" origin_xyz="0 0 0.4"
              mass="57.906"
              ixx="12.679" ixy="0" ixz="0"
              iyy="12.679" iyz="0"
              izz="0.651"
              radius="0.15" length="0.8" />
              
  <m_joint name="${link_04_name}__${link_05_name}" type="revolute"
           axis_xyz="0 0 1"
           origin_rpy="0 0 0" origin_xyz="0 0 0.8"
           parent="link_04" child="link_05"
           limit_e="1000" limit_l="-3.14" limit_u="3.14" limit_v="0.5" />
           
  <m_link_cylinder name="${link_05_name}"
              origin_rpy="0 0 0" origin_xyz="0 0 0.125"
              mass="18.056"
              ixx="0.479" ixy="0" ixz="0"
              iyy="0.479" iyz="0"
              izz="0.204"
              radius="0.15" length="0.25" />

  <sensor_r435 name="Camera 1" parent="${link_05_name}">
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="1 0 0"/>
  </sensor_r435>  

  
<sensor_r435 name="Camera 2" parent="${link_05_name}">
    <origin xyz="0.17 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  </sensor_r435>
  
  <gazebo>
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>
  
</robot>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the realsense xacro doesn't have a "name" parameter which you are supplying, so it doesn't seem to do anything.  Ideally, you can modify the intel xacro line -
`<xacro:macro name="sensor_d415" params="parent *origin">`
to
`<xacro:macro name="sensor_d415" params="sensor_name parent *origin">`
then add `${sensor_name}`to every link and frame name in the intel xacro. Thus when you include this xacro in your URDF with different sensor_name, you recreate the full description each time.

If you get this working cleanly, please do submit a pull request to the intel github page.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime while waiting for a response I made a second file and added 2 to the end of each variable and that worked. Of course I knew this was not a permanent solution and that I should just keep it to one file. Thanks to Vik I have a solution. I took all the variables from my second file and replaced them with ${sensor_name}. For some reason the camera doesn't show up in rviz anymore. I'm not given any error messages but they just disappeared. Are there any issues with my code that people can see?

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
License: Apache 2.0. See LICENSE file in root directory.
Copyright(c) 2017 Intel Corporation. All Rights Reserved

This is the URDF model for the Intel RealSense 430 camera, in it's
aluminum peripherial evaluation case.
-->

<robot name="sensor_d4352" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">
  <xacro:macro name="sensor_d415" params="sensor_name parent *origin">
    <xacro:property name="M_PI" value="3.1415926535897931" />

    <!-- The following values are approximate, and the camera node
     publishing TF values with actual calibrated camera extrinsic values -->
    <xacro:property name="d435_cam_depth_to_left_ir_offset" value="0.0"/>
    <xacro:property name="d435_cam_depth_to_right_ir_offset" value="-0.050"/>
    <xacro:property name="d435_cam_depth_to_color_offset" value="0.015"/>

    <!-- The following values model the aluminum peripherial case for the
    D435 camera, with the camera joint represented by the actual 
    peripherial camera tripod mount -->
    <xacro:property name="d435_cam_width" value="0.090"/>
    <xacro:property name="d435_cam_height" value="0.025"/>
    <xacro:property name="d435_cam_depth" value="0.02505"/>
    <xacro:property name="d435_cam_mount_from_center_offset" value="0.0149"/>

    <!-- The following offset is relative the the physical D435 camera peripherial
    camera tripod mount -->
    <xacro:property name="d435_cam_depth_px" value="${d435_cam_mount_from_center_offset}"/>
    <xacro:property name="d435_cam_depth_py" value="0.0175"/>
    <xacro:property name="d435_cam_depth_pz" value="${d435_cam_height/2}"/>

    <material name="aluminum${sensor_name}">
      <color rgba="0.5 0.5 0.5 1"/>
    </material>


    <!-- camera body, with origin at bottom screw mount -->
    <joint name="camera_joint${sensor_name}" type="fixed">
      <xacro:insert_block name="origin" />
      <parent link="${parent}"/>
      <child link="camera_bottom_screw_frame${sensor_name}" />
    </joint>
    <link name="camera_bottom_screw_frame${sensor_name}"/>

    <joint name="camera_link_joint${sensor_name}" type="fixed">
      <origin xyz="0 ${d435_cam_depth_py} ${d435_cam_depth_pz}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <parent link="camera_bottom_screw_frame${sensor_name}"/>
      <child link="camera_link${sensor_name}" />
    </joint>

    <link name="camera_link${sensor_name}">
      <visual>
      <origin xyz="${d435_cam_mount_from_center_offset} ${-d435_cam_depth_py} 0" rpy="${M_PI/2} 0 ${M_PI/2}"/>
        <geometry>
          <!-- <box size="${d435_cam_width} ${d435_cam_height} ${d435_cam_depth}"/> -->
      <mesh filename="package://realsense2_camera/meshes/d435.dae" />
          <!--<mesh filename="package://realsense2_camera/meshes/d435/d435.dae" />-->

        </geometry>
        <material name="aluminum"/>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 ${-d435_cam_depth_py} 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
        <box size="${d435_cam_depth} ${d435_cam_width} ${d435_cam_height}"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <inertial>
        <!-- The following are not reliable values, and should not be used for modeling -->
        <mass value="0.564" />
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" />
        <inertia ixx="0.003881243" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.000498940" iyz="0.0" izz="0.003879257" />
      </inertial>
    </link>


<!-- camera depth joints and links -->
<joint name="camera_depth_joint${sensor_name}" type="fixed">
  <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="camera_link${sensor_name}"/>
  <child link="camera_depth_frame${sensor_name}" />
</joint>
<link name="camera_depth_frame${sensor_name}"/>

<joint name="camera_depth_optical_joint${sensor_name}" type="fixed">
  <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${-M_PI/2} 0 ${-M_PI/2}" />
  <parent link="camera_depth_frame${sensor_name}" />
  <child link="camera_depth_optical_frame${sensor_name}" />
</joint>
<link name="camera_depth_optical_frame${sensor_name}"/>

<!-- camera left IR joints and links -->
<joint name="camera_left_ir_joint${sensor_name}" type="fixed">
  <origin xyz="0 ${d435_cam_depth_to_left_ir_offset} 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
  <parent link="camera_depth_frame${sensor_name}" />
  <child link="camera_left_ir_frame${sensor_name}" />
</joint>
<link name="camera_left_ir_frame${sensor_name}"/>

<joint name="camera_left_ir_optical_joint${sensor_name}" type="fixed">
  <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${-M_PI/2} 0 ${-M_PI/2}" />
  <parent link="camera_left_ir_frame${sensor_name}" />
  <child link="camera_left_ir_optical_frame${sensor_name}" />
</joint>
<link name="camera_left_ir_optical_frame${sensor_name}"/>

<!-- camera right IR joints and links -->
<joint name="camera_right_ir_joint${sensor_name}" type="fixed">
  <origin xyz="0 ${d435_cam_depth_to_right_ir_offset} 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
  <parent link="camera_depth_frame${sensor_name}" />
  <child link="camera_right_ir_frame${sensor_name}" />
</joint>
<link name="camera_right_ir_frame${sensor_name}"/>

<joint name="camera_right_ir_optical_joint${sensor_name}" type="fixed">
  <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${-M_PI/2} 0 ${-M_PI/2}" />
  <parent link="camera_right_ir_frame${sensor_name}" />
  <child link="camera_right_ir_optical_frame${sensor_name}" />
</joint>
<link name="camera_right_ir_optical_frame${sensor_name}"/>

<!-- camera color joints and links -->
<joint name="camera_color_joint${sensor_name}" type="fixed">
  <origin xyz="0 ${d435_cam_depth_to_color_offset} 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
  <parent link="camera_depth_frame" />
  <child link="camera_color_frame${sensor_name}" />
</joint>
<link name="camera_color_frame${sensor_name}"/>

<joint name="camera_color_optical_joint${sensor_name}" type="fixed">
  <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${-M_PI/2} 0 ${-M_PI/2}" />
  <parent link="camera_color_frame${sensor_name}" />
  <child link="camera_color_optical_frame${sensor_name}" />
</joint>
<link name="camera_color_optical_frame"/>
</xacro:macro>
</robot>
```